# R: Convert list of data.frames to list of raster

Tags: r, list, dataframe, raster

Let's say I have a list of `data.frames`:

```
a1<-as.data.frame(1:9)
a2<-as.data.frame(2:10)
a3<-as.data.frame(3:11)

a.list<-list(a1,a2,a3)
```

Now I want to convert each data.frame of the list into a 3 by 3 `raster` layer. The layers should be in a list afterwards.

I tried to perform this with `lapply`, but can't really tell what the problem is:

```
r.list<-lapply(a.list, raster(nrows=3, ncols=3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to convert your dataframes to matrices first. Exploit the fact that you have 1-column data frames to convert them to vectors and then use the `matrix` function:

```
> rl = lapply(a.list, function(X) raster(matrix(X[,1],nrow=3)))
> rl[[1]]
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 3, 3, 9  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.3333333, 0.3333333  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 1, 9  (min, max)
```

You may want to make sure the rasters are being constructed row-wise or column-wise - use the `byrow` arg to `matrix` to adjust this, or transpose the matrix or otherwise arrange it.

Comment: This works for the 3 by 3 `raster`. As I would like to use it for different dimension I've modified your solution for a more general case: `rl= rl = lapply(a.list, function(X) matrix(X,nrow=3,ncol=3))` and then: `rl= lapply(rl, function(X) raster(X))`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to convert `nrows=3` into a `raster` object, and then apply that new object as a function operating on each element of `a.list`.

You want either:

```
lapply(a.list, raster, nrows=3, ncols=3)
```

Or:

```
lapply(a.list, function(X) raster(X, nrows=3, ncols=3))
```

Comment: Did you actually try this code? Because it doesn't work for me. `unused argument(s) (nrows = 3, ncols = 3)`

Comment: Then the problem is in `raster` and not just with OP's use of `lapply`

Comment: No, the problem is `lapply` calling `raster` with the list element as an argument, and `raster` won't convert that into an nrows x ncols raster, which is documented.

Comment: The problem with the OP's function is he wasn't using raster on the correct object type, and also wasn't calling it through lapply correctly.